Simplifying an integral in order to determine a constant
I have the following equation:
$$\frac{\pi \cot\theta}{A} = \int^{\pi}_0\frac{p^2}{R^2}\cos\kappa d\kappa$$
The following are constant for the above equation: $\theta$, $A$, $R$.  I am trying to solve for $A$.  The expression for $\frac{p}{R}$ is ugly.
$$\frac{p}{R} = \frac{\frac{w\cos\kappa\sin^2\theta}{R}+(-\frac{w^2}{R^2}\sin^2\theta\sin^2\kappa + \sin^2\kappa + \cos^2\kappa\sin^2\theta)^{0.5}}{\sin^2\kappa+\sin^2\theta\cos^2\kappa}$$
However, at $\kappa = \pi$ and $\kappa = 0$, the expressions are quite simple:
$$\left(\frac{p}{R}\right)_\pi = \frac{1}{\sin\theta} - \frac{w}{R}$$
$$\left(\frac{p}{R}\right)_0 = \frac{1}{\sin\theta} + \frac{w}{R}$$
What would be nice is if I can get a reasonably simple expression for $A$ in terms of $\theta$ and $w$.  I thought by using simple expressions for $p$ it would help.  But if I have relatively simple expressions for $p$ at specific values of $\kappa$, I don't know how I can insert them into the integral equation, if I can even do it at all. $A$ is not a function of $\kappa$. Any thoughts are appreciated.
Edit:  I should mention that $A$ lies between $0$ and $1$ and cannot exceed $1$.  I do know that if $\frac{w}{R} = \cot \theta$ then $A = 1$. One other thing is that I believe that the lower limit on $A$ is $\cos\theta$, but I am not sure.
Edit:  A good estimate of how $A$ is related to $\frac{w}{R}$ and $\theta$ might also work.

$\kappa$ is your variable of integration, so it shouldn't appear at all in your final result. Is $p$ not a constant (you didn't include it in the list), and if not what does it depend on?  (If $p$ is a constant then that integral is just zero and there's nothing going on here.)

Also a $w$ has appeared that I have no idea what it is supposed to be.

Yes, as stated A is not a function of $\kappa$.  $p$ is not constant and does vary with $\kappa$ as you can see from the two simplified equations. $w$ is hard to explain but it does have physical meaning.  I'm not sure its physical meaning is relevant to the math.  One other thing, while I stated that the lower limit of $A$ might be $cos\theta$, numerical integration of the integral never is able to converge to that result.  Are there no options mathematically?  How else might I approach this to get a simpler "estimate" of how A depends on w and $\theta$.

I apologize -- for some reason, I thought you had gotten that expression for $p/R$ from integrating, as opposed to it being the thing you were integrating, I don't know where I got that piece of idiocy from.
As tempting as it is with that naked $\cos\kappa$ hanging out at the end, to try to make that a $du$ (by rewriting all the "internal" $\cos^2\kappa$ bits as $(1-\sin^2\kappa)$) I'd be surprised if it gives a closed-form, but I'll poke at that a bit more.

Since $p/R$ is of the form $\sqrt{a}+b$ with $a$ invariant under $\kappa\mapsto\pi-\kappa$ and $b$ multiplying by $-1$ under the same operation as does $\cos\kappa$,$$\int_0^\pi(\sqrt{a}+b)^2\cos\kappa d\kappa=\int_0^{\pi/2}4b\sqrt{a}\cos\kappa d\kappa.$$After that, try Bioche's rules.

So, to use your equation, do I need to include the denominator for p/R within a and b?  If so, then
$$b = \frac{\frac{w\cos\kappa\sin^2\theta}{R}}{\sin^2\kappa+\sin^2\theta\cos^2\kappa}$$
and a would need to be defined similarly by squaring the denominator and bringing it under the square root?
